# Java Action listeners and Images in one class

Tags: java, swing, tags

I have this problem in a program which changes panels in a JFrame. I know how to use action listeners, but I already have a component I use for my image. Can someone help me?

```
package javaapplication3;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JavaApplication3 extends Component {
    BufferedImage img;
    public JavaApplication3(){
        try {img = ImageIO.read(new File("a.jpg"));}catch (IOException e) {}}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p.add(b);
        p1.add(new JavaApplication3());
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setSize(150,150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }}
```

Comment: You are extending from Component, but not implementing any listeners. You can implement how many as you please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both an extension and implmentation of multiple interfaces for a class so it would be

```
class JavaApplication3 extends Component implements ActionListener
```

For a reference on interfaces in java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Vs

Inheritance of classes in java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html